# Error occurred while attempting to load the selected version of R

Tags: r, rstudio

Last night RStudio was working fine. Now it displays the following error when I try to run it:

[image]

I made a change to my system variables' PATH variable yesterday and it's the only thing I can think of that may have broke something. I can't remember what it used to be when things were working fine but I set it to this now:

[image]

I have tried re-installing. I have tried installing an older version of RStudio. I have tested multiple versions of R. R itself is working fine in a terminal. I have tried `--run-diagnostics` which gives the following result:

[image]

UPDATE: Okay, so I managed to fix the issue. Unfortunately it was the result of some bad science where I tried a myriad of different things so I'm not sure which thing actually fixed it. I ran RStudio as administrator, I then chose to browse my files and selected 'RSetReg.exe in the R-4.X.X/bin/x64 folder. This caused the R logo to pop up for a bit. I then ended the task in task manager along with all R related processes. I then launched RStudio by double clicking a .rmd out of sheer hopelessness and it worked for some reason. Perhaps an R process was preventing RStudio from accessing R? Not too sure, just glad it's working again.

Comment: (1) I don't know if it's relevant, but on my system the PATH references `C:\R\R-4.2.2\bin\x64` (the `x64` on the end), not `C:\R\R-4.2.2\bin`. (2) I always recommend windows users install R in a non-default location (_not_ under `C:\Program Files`) due to how it often hiccups/fails with spaces in the executable path. As you can see above, I install into `C:\R\...`. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f. Perhaps not "the" culprit, but a consideration.

Comment: @r2evans R works just fine with spaces in the path name on Windows. Do you have a concrete example of it failing? And except for Make ([and `R` on POSIX …](https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/5ddbc725a873a195cc423a6da4417d05015c58fe/R/paths.r#L135-L144)) there is no commonly-used software that has *any* issues whatsoever with spaces in paths.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Reinstalled R to C:\R\... but no luck. Also changed my PATH accordingly and included the \x64 this time but no luck there either, still the same error message.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, all of my experience of things failing on windows due to spaces in the path were years ago, I have since never felt the need to move my R installation to a space-infused path just for the sake of testing it. Perhaps I'll do that on the next computer refresh. Regardless, while I recognize that R-core documentation is not necessarily updated often, the fact that they still have the disclaimer does suggest recognition that _something_ didn't like the space, whether R-core or otherwise. The fact that it "should be fine" is something we agree on, anecdotally not always sufficient.

Comment: Can you open R outside of RStudio? You should be able to use the standard R GUI. If you can do that, what is the output of `R.home("bin")`? Does that match what you have in your path? Can you get to Tools...Global Options in RStudio? Is there an R Version set there? What is that path? If you click "Change", is it set to use your machine default or a specific path?

Comment: The output of R.home('bin') is:

> R.home('bin')
[1] "C:/R/R-4.2.3/bin/x64"

Which does match the path I have set. I can't get to tools I don't think, I get stuck at this screen:

https://i.imgur.com/aKwXnrW.png

Thanks for the continued help

Comment: Given that v4.3 just came out a couple of weeks ago, how about using this problem as an excuse to completely nuke and reinstall? Remove all R/R studio software, delete the 4.2 folder in `C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/R/win-library`. Install R v4.3 and reinstall RStudio. Note that if you have any packages that are not on CRAN you should make note as to how you got them because all packages will also need to be reinstalled.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "there is no commonly-used software that has any issues whatsoever with spaces in paths" I was under the impression that LaTeX doesn't like spaces in path/file names.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I uninstalled R. Deleted the Folder. Uninstalled RStudio. Reinstalled latest R version. Installed latest RStudio version. updated system PATH variable to account for change in R version. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't understand why R is not being installed within the Program Files folder. Are you pointing to to not have it installed there?

Comment: It is back to the program files folder now. I changed its location as per r2evans' suggestion to see if it was an issue with the space in 'Program Files'.

Comment: @Phil That's no longer true (and even before there were ways of working around this bug by patching the commands manually and/or quoting the spaces).